# What is a good low-impact network printer/scanner?

Tags: networking, printer, multi-function-printer

- I want a printer that doesn't require me to install a bunch of custom software of each PC on the network. I want to just **Add Network Printer** from each Windows PC, and be done.
- I want a scanner that will scan to a network share (on my Windows Home Server).  Simple interface required: I want to put a peice of paper in the scanner, hit 1 button, and be done.

Being all-in-one is nice, but not required. I will buy two units if that's what it takes.

Ideally it's Wi-Fi, so I can just plop it down anywhere, but if I have to plug in to my WHS, that is acceptable.

I don't print or scan very often, so it doesn't have to be fast. Ideally the ink cartridges are small, so they don't expire before I use them up. Laser is OK, if it's not too expensive, but not required.  Color laser is an acceptable option, since the toner lasts a long time.

Ideally it's a physically small unit.

This is an all-Windows household, so Linux and Mac compatibility isn't required.

What should I get?

Comment: Bounty removed. Adding a bounty to a question that is 3 months, and can have an every evolving answer makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

1. I have had very good luck with HP All-in-ones.  I have an oldish HP 2110 that hase been working great for years.  It's a USB printer that I hooked up a wireless print server to.  A friend has a newer [HP C4780](http://www.shopping.hp.com/webapp/shopping/store_access.do?template_type=product_detail&product_code=Q8380A%23ABA&jumpid=re_r602_ep_cc_na_ipg_oct09_wireless) - it's small footprint & easy setup.  HP printers typically are at the top of the charts at [Consumers Reports](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/electronics-computers/computers-internet/printers/all-in-one-printer-ratings/ratings-overview.htm).  Disclosure: My sister-in-law used to be a firmware programmer for HP - printers & faxes.
2. I never install the printer software that comes with a printer.  The benfit of the manufacturer driver is outweighed by all the trash that comes with it.  On my linux, connecting up to a wireless printer via ipp is essentially automatic.  I would expect that as soon as you configure your wireless printer to join the network, all the PC's on your network will be able to find it & print without installing anything.  Worst case scenario, you might have to provide the URI to the printer, for example, my printer is at `ipp://192.168.2.110:631/ipp/P1/`

Comment: I also like the HP All-in-ones, but check on the wireless compatibility before you buy.  I ended up with one that was supposed to support WPA and as it turns out no one who actually tried to use it can get it to work.  So instead of downgrading my network to use WEP I had to add another AP.